# How to handle positioned element (in Stack) on different screen sizes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Following is the code that has a stack and some positioned widgets in it.

```
       Stack(
            children: [

              Positioned(
                top: 50,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 30,
                child: Text(
                  'Mon-Sat',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              Positioned(
                top: 70,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 30,
                child: Text(
                  '11:00 PM',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Image.asset(Images.calendar),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

[image]

Now this UI code is working fine on a specific 6 inches screen, but on smaller screens, the positioned elements change their positions (as expected).

So, how I can handle this positioned element on different screen sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the height and width of the screen your app is run and then specify the relative positions from top, left, height and width. The code below demonstrates the use of MediaQuery.of(context).size with which you can find the width and height of the screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    double side = height * 0.10;
    
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: height * 0.10,
          left: width * 0.10,
          child: Container(height: side, width: side, color: Colors.red),
        ),
       Positioned(
          top: height * 0.10,
          left: width * 0.70,
          child: Container(height: side, width: side, color: Colors.green),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: height * 0.70,
          left: width * 0.70,
          child: Container(height: side, width: side, color: Colors.red),
        ),
       Positioned(
          top: height * 0.70,
          left: width * 0.10,
          child: Container(height: side, width: side, color: Colors.green),
        ),        
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I have a specific `top` and `left` and a dynamic number of `Positioned` widgets how could I recalculate them?

Comment: @snuz were you able to figure that out? I'm facing the same issue.